# Learn Python The Hard Way ex35

Tags: python

I was doing Excersice 35 ( Branches and Functions ) but the code I type in didn't work, after some time looking for mistakes, I tried to copy-paste from the book, but it didn't work

Here the code:

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():

    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")


def bear_room():

    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

while True:

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "take honey":
        dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
        print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
        bear_moved = True
    elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
        gold_room()
    else:
        print "I got no idea what that means."


def cthulhu_room():

    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()


def dead(why):

    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def start():

    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")



start()
```

When I run it, it appears ">", that is the while-loop, but when I type "take honey", it says that dead isn't defined, I'm not understanding. ( Sorry if I wrote something wrong in english )

Comment: Nothing in your posted code shows where `dead()` is defined - where is this function? Does it exist?

Comment: Yeah it's right above `start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation in python matters a lot, it looks like you did not indent the `while` statement, the whole thing under `while` including `while` itself should belong under `def bear_room()`.

The `bear_room` should be like this or else you're running the `while` loop before the `start()` call:

```
def bear_room():

    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

    while True:

        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."
```

Comment: OHHH haha I didn't see that, now it's working, I don't know how I didn't notice that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function definition of `dead` to the top of the file (above where it's invoked).

```
from sys import exit

def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def gold_room():

    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")


def bear_room():

    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False

while True:

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "take honey":
        dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
        print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
        bear_moved = True
    elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
        gold_room()
    else:
        print "I got no idea what that means."


def cthulhu_room():

    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()




def start():

    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")


start()
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but it does not go by the logic of this question. The OP stated "copy-paste from the book" which must've meant that `dead` was there in the book too. And plus, according to your logic, you're running the while loop before the `start`, in which it explains the setting of the game

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a whitespace error in your code. That means you forgot a tab some place and therefore your definition of `dead` (the function) is never reached. When it is called then (`dead("...")`) it's not defined and your script stops.

Here's how your code should look like:

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")

def bear_room():
    print "There is a bear here."
    print "The bear has a bunch of honey."
    print "The fat bear is in front of another door."
    print "How are you going to move the bear?"
    bear_moved = False
    while True:
        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "take honey":
            dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
        elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
            print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
            bear_moved = True
        elif next == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
            dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
        elif next == "open door" and bear_moved:
            gold_room()
        else:
            print "I got no idea what that means."

def cthulhu_room():
    print "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
    print "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
    print "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if "flee" in next:
        start()
    elif "head" in next:
        dead("Well that was tasty!")
    else:
        cthulhu_room()

def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

def start():
    print "You are in a dark room."
    print "There is a door to your right and left."
    print "Which one do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "left":
        bear_room()
    elif next == "right":
        cthulhu_room()
    else:
        dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")

start()
```

Really pay attention to the whitespaces!